# Passing data from one controller to another without using query string - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have the `model` as below

```
@Service
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class InfoHandler {

    String url;

    public String getBeanData() {
        String application = "testApplication";
        String mode = "appMode";
        url = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath("/nextPage")
                .queryParam("mode", mode)
                .queryParam("application", application)
                .build()
                .toUriString();
        return url;
    }
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@ComponentScan("com.springplay")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class InfoController {

    @RequestMapping("/getInfo")
    public ModelAndView getInfo(ModelMap model) {
        InfoHandler infoHandler = new InfoHandler();
        //List<InfoBean> beanList = infoHandler.getBeanData();
        String url = infoHandler.getBeanData();
        return new ModelAndView("Information", "urlData", url);
    }
}
```

**My View:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Information Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%-- <c:set var="informationVar" value="${infoData}" /> --%>

<a href="${urlData}"> link to next page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

In my next controller I'm accessing the value of `application` and `mode` using `@RequestParam` in the method argument which works perfectly fine as below

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
@ComponentScan("com.springplay")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class InfoProcessorController {

    @RequestMapping("/nextPage")
    public String getInfo(ModelMap model, @RequestParam(value = "application") String application,
            @RequestParam(value = "mode") String mode) {
        System.out.println("application: " + application);
        System.out.println("mode: " + mode);
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

But my question is, Is there any other way to get the values of `application` and `modes` in the `InfoHandler` class to the `InfoProcessorController` which is my second `controller`

This is just an example. The reason why I don't want to pass data through query string is because I have a lot of such variables that I want to pass to the second controller

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your really expecting, you know you put them as parameters as your question shows, you could put them in the session, this is typically what is done for shopping carts ect. If you are doing something substantial with a long list of pages the use needs to go through and fill out you may want to take a look at Spring Webflow. That could be what your after. It's a bit hard to tell what your asking because it's unclear how you want to pass them, or what you would be happy with, I suggest making your question more clear.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, if I pass it as query string I can achieve what I need, But there is a long of attributes and values that needs to be passed. So that's why I want to understand if there are any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways of doing that

- Pass variables in session
- Pass variables using post method so that they will not be appeared in query param
- Save in cookie and access back at server side (never recommended to do like this)

Comment: can you pls provide an example for #2?

Comment: You can check this example for POST request :
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-form-handling-annotation-example/
Session : http://www.javaroots.com/2013/08/how-to-get-session-object-in-spring-mvc.html